# Iterate nested map with range for loop: has no member named ‘first’

Tags: c++

How can I iterate over a nested `std::map`? This code will not compile:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>

using ssmap = std::map<int,  std::map<std::string,std::string>>;

int main() {
    ssmap map = {
        {1, {{"Brown","Manager"}, {"Smith", "Salesman"}, {"Albert", "Salesman"}}},
        {2, {{"Penfold", "Designer"}, {"Evans", "Tea-person"}, {"Jurgens", "Manager"}}}
    };
    for (auto const& item : map) {
        std::cout << map.first << "\n";
    }  
    return 0;
}
```

The error message is:

```
test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cpp:13:26: error: ‘using ssmap = class std::map<int, std::map<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >’ {aka ‘class std::map<int, std::map<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >’} has no member named ‘first’
   13 |         std::cout << map.first << "\n";
      |                          ^~~~~
```

Comment: Change the content of the for loop to `std::cout << item.first << "\n";`

Comment: `map.first` -> `item.first`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to change `map.first` to `item.first` in your for loop.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>

using ssmap = std::map<int,  std::map<std::string,std::string>>;

int main() {
    ssmap map = {
        {1, {{"Brown","Manager"}, {"Smith", "Salesman"}, {"Albert", "Salesman"}}},
        {2, {{"Penfold", "Designer"}, {"Evans", "Tea-person"}, {"Jurgens", "Manager"}}}
    };

    for (auto const& item : map) {
        std::cout << item.first << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```